# Changing Eclipse Dock Icon

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, icons, dock

So a while back, I downloaded Eclipse for JS developers. It always launched with the "JS" icon showing in my Win7 dock. Recently, I started using Eclipse for Java EE development, as well. But regardless of what perspective I'm using, the dock icon still says "JS." Now, I'm the kind of person whom that really annoys. Is there any way to change the dock icon WITHOUT re-installing Eclipse?

Comment: Doesn't the dock allow you to change the properties of the programs there?

Comment: I created a gist which explains how to do that: https://gist.github.com/marlonbernardes/d3d7fd75ee689c2b989b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse allows the redefinition of Dock icons using different products. The various packages of Eclipse provide such products, e.g. there is a different icon for Java EE package.

I think, but not entirely sure, that you are experiencing such an icon change. To resolve it, you have to manually edit the eclipse.ini file next to eclipse.exe - make sure you make a backup before editing!

Look for a line similar to the following:

```
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
```

The org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product is an Eclipse product id that is launched and that provides the icon, splash screen, etc. If you replace that line with a different product, you can get back the original icon after a restart.

How to determine the correct product ID:

1. If it begins with org.eclipse.epp it is a deployed edition downloaded from eclipse.org - in this case, it probably wasn't that the issue (unless you are complaining about the Java EE packages specific icon).
2. With no plug-in development knowledge: download a new copy of Eclipse, and look for its eclipse.ini file. You don't have to start it, just copy the correct line.
3. If you have the Plug-in development environment installed, and you are using it, then simply open a Run configuration, and on the Main tab look for the Product list dropdown - the listed ones are all valid and installed products.
4. Hard-core solution: you can ask the p2 director from the command line of the installed products. Unless you are experienced with this tool, don't try to use this solution (step 2 or 3 is much simpler).

Comment: What worked for me: REMOVING the --product line and the following line entirely. This changed the ugly J2EE icon to the way nicer Juno icon. Thanks!

Comment: Works for Neon.1 - i used: org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

Comment: Works for 2021/3 too, thanks!